# Mouvement se rapprochant ou s'éloignant d'un centre

Tags: vocabulaire, mathématiques, physique

Je travaille actuellement sur un domaine ayant trait aux ellipses. Je cherche deux adjectifs antonymes pour qualifier un mouvement :

- Un adjectif pour qualifier un mouvement qui s'éloigne d'un centre donné.
- Un adjectif pour qualifier un mouvement qui se rapproche d'un centre donné.

J'avais dans un premier temps pensé aux adjectifs « concentrique » et « excentrique », mais il s'avère que ces deux termes signifient des choses différentes. Y a-t-il dans la langue française des mots qui correspondraient précisément aux définitions données ci-dessus ou bien dois-je me contenter de leurs définitions ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Si on parle de la trajectoire d'un mobile *le long* d'une ellipse, comme par exemple la trajectoire elliptique d'une comète autour du soleil, on peut s'inspirer les termes astronomiques, comme apogée/périgée, aphélie/périhélie...

Ces termes désignent les points particulier de l'ellipse: le point le plus proche (*péri-*) ou le plus éloigné (*a-*) d'un foyer particulier (on emploie plus couramment *foyers* que *centres* dans le cas d'une ellipse). En astronomie, en fonction de l'objet occupant ce foyer, on utilisera des termes différents : apogée/périgée pour la terre, aphélie/périhélie pour le soleil, etc. Dans le cas général, utilisable en mathématique je suppose, les termes sont apoapside/périapside.

On peut donc décrire le mouvement le long de l'ellipse comme *se rapprochant/s'éloignant de l'apoapside/du périapside*. Mais à ma connaissance, il n'existe pas de terme pour exprimer ceci en un seul mot.

Comment: Je devais être très fatigué hier, j'ai écrit « ellipse » alors que je pensais clairement aux spirales. Du coup, bien que cette réponse ne réponde pas à mon problème (c'est ma faute), elle est très pertinente :)

Comment: Enfin bon, la question est telle qu'elle est ; je ne vais pas la changer. Du coup, j'accepte cette réponse.

Answer (score 8):

Les mots que tu cherches sont [*centrifuge*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/centrifuge), « qui tend à s'éloigner du centre » et [*centripète*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/centrip%C3%A8te) « qui tend à se rapprocher du centre ». On les emploie couramment pour parler de *force centrifuge* ou de *force centripète*.

Comment: Je connaissais bien ces adjectifs dans le cadre de forces, mais il ne me serait jamais venu à l'idée de les employer pour qualifier d'autres choses. Merci :)